# Поиск даты в строке

Tags: c#

Входная строка: "`01.05.2017 - Задача 1`". Какой оптимальный подход, получить из строки дату?

Comment: Regex по паттерну DD.MM.YYYY - Задача %d.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтото примерно такое, вот только с регулярками я не дружу, поетому надо с етим вопросом разобраться :)

```
string a = "01.05.2017 - Задача 1";
Match match = Regex.Match(a, @"\d\d[.]\d\d[.]\d\d\d\d");
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Captures[0].Value);
}
```

А так можно получить все совпадения в строке :

```
string a = "01.05.2017 - Задача 1";
Match match = Regex.Match(a, @"\d\d[.]\d\d[.]\d\d\d\d");
while (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

Comment: Только наверное лучше: `\d+[-]?\d+[.]\d+[.]\d+`, тогда распознает дату `10-12.06.2017`

Answer (score 3):

Без регулярных выражений будет работать шустрее, при условии неизменности формата входных строк:

```
var str = "01.05.2017 - Задача 1";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(str.Substring(0, 10), "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно , если строка всё время подается в таком формате, то можно взять подстроку (.substring) с двумя параметрами `startindex`, `endindex`, указав начальный и конечный символ даты.